# Selecting the file with the biggest size in a folder than applying couple of functions in Python

Tags: python, function, sys

I am interested in finding the files with the biggest size in terms of kbs in a folder and then apply a function. After that, I want to apply a different function to remaining files in the same folder. If I knew which files I was going to use, names and sizes of the files, I would use the following code:

```
with open(big_file, 'r') as bigfile:
   bigfile.rotate #predefined function
   minx, maxx, miny, maxy, minz, maxz = find_mins_maxs(bigfile) #predefined function
   w1 = maxx - minx
   l1 = maxy - miny
   h1 = maxz - minz
   copies = copy_obj(bigfile, (w1, l1, h1), 2, 2, 1)
with open(small_file, 'r') as smallfile:
    minx, maxx, miny, maxy, minz, maxz = find_mins_maxs(smallfile)
    w2 = maxx - minx
    l2 = maxy - miny
    h2 = maxz - minz
    translate(smallfile, w1, w1 / 10., 3, 'x')
    copies2 = copy_obj(smallfile, (w2, l2, h2), 2, 2, 1)
    combined = mesh.Mesh(numpy.concatenate([bigfile.data, smallfile.data] +
                                [copy.data for copy in copies] +
                                [copy.data for copy in copies2]))
    combined.save(folder + '.stl', mode=stl.Mode.ASCII)  # save as ASCII
```

How I could apply it to many folders that consist of many files

Comment: `os.stat(fname).st_size` should tell you the size of any given file (according to the OS) (i think its `st_size` attribute at least ...

Comment: then I should write a loop for remaining files?

Comment: thats probably a reasonable method to check many files

Comment: What I mean is after finding and applying the first step to the file with the biggest size, how can I loop through other files to apply second step

Answer (score 1):

This finds the biggest file in a given directory:

```
import os
path = '/path/to/directory'
print(max(os.listdir(path), key=lambda x: os.stat(os.path.join(path,x)).st_size))
```

Comment: that doesn't work unless you're listing the current directory because `listdir` returns the file names, not paths.

Comment: (just use glob.glob instead of os.listdir and your good ... or do os.path.join)

Comment: `max(glob.glob('/path/to/directory/*'), key=os.path.getsize)`

Comment: Corrected. Unless I'm mistaken, `glob.glob` won't include hidden files (dot-files in Unix).

Comment: and `stat` / `getsize` return a different result for directories. It would be better to filter them out.

Comment: @Błotosmętek ... hmm thats cool... I did not know it didnt list hidden files,good to know (I dont learn new python stuffs very often)

Comment: Oh, I have started learning Python quite recently, but glob works the same way in Perl, and I have ~15 years of Perl experience.

Comment: This will fail if the smallest file in the directory is smaller than a directory entry - e.g. in a directory with subdirectories and a 1byte file - it will declare one of the subdirectories as the 'biggest file'.

Answer (score 1):

Just list your files with `os.listdir`, check for files using `os.path.isfile` and use `os.stat` for a more reliable size readout, store them in a list and sort that list:

```
import os

target = "."  # let's use the current dir as our target

file_list = sorted((os.stat(os.path.join(target, f)).st_size, os.path.join(target, f))
                    for f in os.listdir(target)
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(target, f)))
```

Now your `file_list` will contain a list of tuples `(file_size, file_path)` ordered from smallest to the biggest size in the `target` directory.

You can then use `file_list[-1][1]` to get the biggest file, and you can loop through all of the others (`file_list[:-1]`) to execute something else on them, e.g.:

```
function_for_the_biggest_file(file_list[-1][1])

for other_file in file_list[:-1]:
    function_for_other_files(other_file[1])
```

**EDIT** - It seems that after you execute your functions you want to save them all in one file, so:

```
with open(os.path.join(target, "combined.dat"), "w") as outfile:
    for files in file_list:
        with open(files[1], "r") as f:
            outfile.write(f.read())
```

This will concentrate all of the files in `combined.dat` in the same directory, in order of the smallest to the biggest file. You can use `for files in reversed(file_list):` if you want to store from the biggest to the smallest file.

Comment: How can i combine them at the end if I don't know the number of files to combine ?

Comment: What do you mean "combine" them? You have them all listed in ascending order in the `file_list`, together with their sizes - you can do whatever you want with the list.

Comment: @Cenk_Mitir - check the update, if I understood what you want correctly. Although if you're already doing something with the contents of the files, you should probably pass an open file handle to the `combined.dat` to your functions so they can write directly to the combined file instead of reading and saving the modified files, just so you can read them again a moment later...

Comment: Actually, I have to combine them in a way that I have done in the question, that is little bit tricky

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.5 and higher, you can do this:

```
import os

direntries = list(os.scandir(PATH))
bigfile = max(direntries, key=lambda x: x.stat().st_size)
```

Now `bigfile` is a [DirEntry object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry). Then `bigfile.name` is the filename, and `bigfile.path` is the full path.

Then you can do

```
dostuff(bigfile)
for f in direntries:
    if f is not bigfile:
       otherstuff(f)
```

Or, if you want to skip directories:

```
for f in direntries:
    if f.is_file() and f is not bigfile:
       otherstuff(f)
```

Comment: but in the end, I have to combine all of them, how I wil lbe able to achieve it?